# change slider value according to the AVSpeechUtterance in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechsynthesizer

I am using `AVSpeechUtterance` for reading text and trying to implement a change slider thumb according to text read.

I've tried :-

```
myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: idFileText)
myUtterance.rate = 0.3

synth.speak(myUtterance)
synth.continueSpeaking() 

if let intValue = Int(idFileText) {
    self.sliderValue.setValue(Float(intValue), 
                              animated: true)
}
```

The text reader is doing well but slider value does not change.
Can any one please suggest me the right way to implement slider on text reader.

Comment: what is the purpose of this slider?

Comment: like music play same as Im trying to implement in text reader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AVSpeechSynthesizer`'s delegate `speechSynthesizer(_:willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString:utterance:)`.
It provides the current character range being spoken.
You can use it to determine the slider position as you should already know the length of the entire text.

A basic example would be:

```
func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, 
                       willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString characterRange: NSRange, 
                       utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
    let progress = Float(characterRange.location + characterRange.length)
                   / Float(utterance.speechString.count)
    print(progress)

    self.sliderValue.setValue(progress, 
                              animated: true)
}
```

For the above logic, ensure your slider object min-max range is 0-1.
And ofcourse, you will need to improve on it to obtain a smoother progress.

---

Don't forget:

```
synth.delegate = self
```

Comment: thanks its working . can you please suggest me if i have audio and text both are there then how can i change slider

Comment: @AnuragMishra will need more details to understand your case but mostly it would be just a matter of proper case handling.

Comment: let urlstring = idAudio ,,let url = NSURL(string: urlstring),,avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url! as URL),, avPlayer = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: avPlayerItem)
                                avPlayer?.play()
             avPlayer?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMake(1, 30), queue: .main) { time in
                        let fraction = CMTimeGetSeconds(time) / CMTimeGetSeconds((self.avPlayer?.currentItem!.duration)!)
                        self.sliderValue.value = Float(fraction)
                    }
 this is my audio coding how can i merge both audio and text reader

Comment: @AnuragMishra It looks fine to me. What's the problem?

Comment: i want to merge both audio and text reader into one slider value

Comment: @AnuragMishra So you play `AVSpeechSynthesizer` & `AVPlayer` at same time? or one after another?

Comment: @AnuragMishra I don't know much of your class structure but when ever you start playing from either source, just reset the `slider` and let the individual logics update the slider value. Not much to it but ensure both sources are not trying to update the slider at the same time.

Comment: @AnuragMishra Since you have a new requirement now, post a new question. Include as much information as required so someone can understand your setup and provide solutions.